# baseDir issue with nextflow

Tags: bioinformatics, nextflow

This might be a very basic question for you guys, however, I am have just started with nextflow and I struggling with the simplest example.

I first explain what I have done and the problem.

Aim: I aim to make a workflow for my bioinformatics analyses as the one here (https://www.nextflow.io/example4.html)

Background: I have installed all the packages that were needed and they all work from the console without any error.

My run: I have used the same script as in example only by replacing the directory names. Here is how I have arranged the directories

```
location of script

~/raman/nflow/script.nf

location of Fastq files

~/raman/nflow/Data/T4_1.fq.gz
~/raman/nflow/Data/T4_2.fq.gz

Location of transcriptomic file

~/raman/nflow/Genome/trans.fa
```

The script

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

/*
 * The following pipeline parameters specify the refence genomes
 * and read pairs and can be provided as command line options
 */
params.reads = "$baseDir/Data/T4_{1,2}.fq.gz"
params.transcriptome = "$baseDir/HumanGenome/SalmonIndex/gencode.v42.transcripts.fa"
params.outdir = "results"

workflow {
    read_pairs_ch = channel.fromFilePairs( params.reads, checkIfExists: true )

    INDEX(params.transcriptome)
    FASTQC(read_pairs_ch)
    QUANT(INDEX.out, read_pairs_ch)
}

process INDEX {
    tag "$transcriptome.simpleName"

    input:
    path transcriptome

    output:
    path 'index'

    script:
    """
    salmon index --threads $task.cpus -t $transcriptome -i index
    """
}

process FASTQC {
    tag "FASTQC on $sample_id"
    publishDir params.outdir

    input:
    tuple val(sample_id), path(reads)

    output:
    path "fastqc_${sample_id}_logs"

    script:
    """
    fastqc "$sample_id" "$reads"
    """
}

process QUANT {
    tag "$pair_id"
    publishDir params.outdir

    input:
    path index
    tuple val(pair_id), path(reads)

    output:
    path pair_id

    script:
    """
    salmon quant --threads $task.cpus --libType=U -i $index -1 ${reads[0]} -2 ${reads[1]} -o $pair_id
    """
}
```

Output:

```
(base) ntr@ser:~/raman/nflow$ nextflow script.nf
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.1
Launching `script.nf` [modest_meninsky] DSL2 - revision: 032a643b56
executor >  local (2)
executor >  local (2)
[-        ] process > INDEX (gencode)       -
[28/02cde5] process > FASTQC (FASTQC on T4) [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
[-        ] process > QUANT                 -
Error executing process > 'FASTQC (FASTQC on T4)'

Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `fastqc_T4_logs` expected by process `FASTQC (FASTQC on T4)`

Command executed:

  fastqc "T4" "T4_1.fq.gz T4_2.fq.gz"

Command exit status:
  0

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  Skipping 'T4' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
  Skipping 'T4_1.fq.gz T4_2.fq.gz' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read

Work dir:
  /home/ruby/raman/nflow/work/28/02cde5184f4accf9a05bc2ded29c50

Tip: view the complete command output by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `cat .command.out`
```

I believe I have an issue with my baseDir understanding. I am assuming that the baseDir is the one where I have my file script.nf I am not sure what is going wrong and how can I fix it.

Could anyone please help or guide.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `fastqc_T4_logs` expected by process `FASTQC (FASTQC on T4)`
```

Nextflow complains when it can't find the declared output files. This can occur even if the command completes successfully, i.e. with exit status 0. The problem here is that `fastqc` simply skips files that don't exist or can't be read (e.g. permissions problems), but it does produce these warnings:

```
Skipping 'T4' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'T4_1.fq.gz T4_2.fq.gz' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
```

The solution is to just make sure all files exist. Note that the [`fromFilePairs`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#fromfilepairs) factory method produces a list of files in the second element. Therefore quoting a space-separated pair of filenames is also problematic. All you need is:

```
script:
"""
fastqc ${reads}
"""
```